# How can i read from UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE> in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift

I want to read a value which is `UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>` .
What is easiest way to do that ? Is it possible to convert it to a String ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by ` read a value which is UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>`? FILE is a C type that points to a file in the file system, and you should use relevant C APIs(fread, fclose, etc.) to read the file contents. UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE> itself has nothing but a memory address.

Comment: @cezheng A function return file descriptor as result. I want to read it like a string. I know its pointer that points to the File Descriptor. I want to read content of the memory, thats my question. I dont know how to use fread function in swift format, please tell me if you know.

Comment: It's the same as you do in C. I will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

C APIs can be directly used from Swift. Writing a function like this can read the file content from FILE pointers.

```
  func stringFromFILE(filePtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>) -> String {
    guard filePtr != nil else {
      return ""
    }
    // change the buffer size at your needs
    let buffer = [CChar](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0)
    var string = String()
    while fgets(UnsafeMutablePointer(buffer), Int32(buffer.count), filePtr) != nil {
      if let read = String.fromCString(buffer) {
        string += read
      }
    }
    return string
  }
```